# Spring data jpa BooleanBuider has call different data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This is my BooleanBuider Code;

this is a Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SelectUnits {
    private String subject;
    private String[] unit1;
}
```

that is very simple.

```
 BooleanBuilder bb = new BooleanBuilder();
```

I has two case

first.

```
bb.and(qs.subject.eq("A").and(qs.unit1.eq("as")))
               .or(qs.subject.eq("B").and(qs.unit1.eq("bs")))
               .or(qs.subject.eq("B").and(qs.unit1.eq("ds")));
```

this is a BooleanBuider value

```
(questions.subject = A && questions.unit1 = as || questions.subject = B && questions.unit1 = bs || questions.subject = B && questions.unit1 = ds)
```

that has correct result

but

```
List<SelectUnits >req = new arraylist<>;
  AtomicInteger counters = new AtomicInteger(1);
   req.stream().forEach(x -> {

            AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

            Arrays.stream(x.getUnit1()).forEach(y -> {

                if (counter.get() == 0&&counters.getAndAdd(1)==1) {
                    bb.and(qs.subject.eq(x.getSubject()).and(qs.unit1.eq(y)));
                } else {
                    bb.or(qs.subject.eq(x.getSubject()).and(qs.unit1.eq(y)));
                }
                counter.getAndAdd(1);
            });


        });
```

this is a BooleanBuider value

```
(questions.subject = A&& questions.unit1 = bs || questions.subject = B && questions.unit1 = bs|| questions.subject = B&& questions.unit1 = ds)
```

this is not correct data.

Two case call same Hibernate code but got a different result.
why BooleanBuider  make a different result?

this is Hibernate:

```
 select
        questions0_.id as id1_7_,
        questions0_.openFiled as openFile2_7_,
        questions0_.publisher as publishe3_7_,
        questions0_.qSize as qSize4_7_,
        questions0_.qType as qType5_7_,
        questions0_.subject as subject6_7_,
        questions0_.unit1 as unit7_7_,
        questions0_.unit2 as unit8_7_,
        questions0_.unit3 as unit9_7_ 
    from
        questions questions0_ 
    where
        (
            questions0_.subject=? 
            and questions0_.unit1=? 
            or questions0_.subject=? 
            and questions0_.unit1=?
        ) 
        and (
            exists (
                select
                    1 
                from
                    questions_list questionli1_ 
                where
                    questions0_.id=questionli1_.questions_id 
                    and (
                        questionli1_.difficult between ? and ?
                    )
            )
        ) 
    order by
        questions0_.subject desc limit ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
 if (counter.get() == 0 && counters.getAndAdd(1) == 1) {
                    bb.and(qs.subject.eq(y.getSubject()).or(qs.unit1.eq(x)));
                } else {
                    bb.or(qs.subject.eq(y.getSubject()).or(qs.unit1.eq(x)));
                }
```